# Using Spark View Engine in a stand alone application

Tags: c#, spark-view-engine

My client application needs to generate HTML. I'd like to use a template/view engine solution like Spark, but I'm not sure whether Spark can be used outside of an ASP.NET application. Does anyone know of any samples or documentation about using Spark in this way?

(If you know of other view engine solutions that can be used stand-alone, I'd be curious to hear about those, too.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In addition to the other examples, I found a simple one in the Spark source itself. The Xpark project is a command-line application for transforming XML using Spark. [Louis DeJardin](http://whereslou.com/), the creator of Spark, described [how Xpark works](http://whereslou.com/2009/03/23/using-xparkexe-to-transform-xml) on his blog.

The relevant code snippets are:

```
    // Create an engine using the templates path as the root location
    // as well as the shared location
    var engine = new SparkViewEngine
        {
             DefaultPageBaseType = typeof(SparkView).FullName,
             ViewFolder = viewFolder.Append(new SubViewFolder(viewFolder, "Shared"))
        };

    SparkView view;

    // compile and instantiate the template
    view = (SparkView)engine.CreateInstance(
                          new SparkViewDescriptor()
                              .AddTemplate(templateName));

    // render the view to stdout
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput(), Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        view.RenderView(writer);
    }
```

This was enough to get me pointed in the right direction. But I'll definitely dive into the other examples as well.

Answer (score 3):

You should check out [Docu](http://docu.jagregory.com/), this project uses the Spark view engine to generate HTML documentation (not from an ASP.NET web application).

*Be warned though, I don't know that the project is using Spark version 1.0, it might be an earlier build.*

http://docu.jagregory.com/

http://github.com/jagregory/docu

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Probably the most complete example is to look at the Spark view engine code for ASP.NET MVC itself.

It's also under test, so reading the tests should give you a very good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps anyone else, I needed to accomplish something similar using the Spark engine outside of an MVC project.
I created a sample (very simplified) C# project of using the Spark view engine to do simple template operations. Maybe someone could use it as a starting point /shrug
http://jezel.googlecode.com/files/SparkTemplateExample.zip

Most of my template code is based off of reviewing [Jonas Gauffin's C# WebServer](http://webserver.codeplex.com/) project where he uses the Spark Engine for templates in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 0):

See the examples in:
https://github.com/SparkViewEngine/spark/tree/master/src/Samples/DirectUsage

Unfortunately these appear to require System.Web.Mvc, which I'd rather not reference.